# C++: No matching function for call to ''

Tags: c++, qt, function, matching

I am having an error in the compiler but I am not sure why it's giving me it. I tried lots of things and I can't figure out what could cause the problem.
There seems to be a problem with loading the progressBar into the energyBar.
When loading other parameters than progressBar, it compiles without errors.

Here is the code:

MaindWindow2.cpp

```
 #include EnergyBar.h
    ...//Other code
  void MainWindow2::drawEnergyBar()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    progressBar = new QProgressBar(ui->statusBar);
    progressBar->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
    progressBar->setMaximumSize(180, 19);
    ui->statusBar->addWidget(progressBar);
    progressBar->setValue(100); //Max is 100%.
    energyBar = new EnergyBar(progressBar);

}
```

Energybar.cpp

```
#include "energybar.h"    


    EnergyBar::EnergyBar(QProgressBar progressBar){     

    }
//Some methods
```

Energybar.h

```
#include "energybar.h"
#include "view.h"
#include "model.h"



EnergyBar::EnergyBar(QProgressBar progressBar){    

}
void EnergyBar::calculateTileEnergy()
{

}
```

I have some other parameters in the constructor of the EnergyBar, but I left them out since they do not cause the problem.
There is no problem creating the new object energyBar if the "progressBar"  is left out.
However adding it causes the error :

```
/home/jb/Documents/nodePtr/mainwindow2.cpp:66: error: no matching function for call to 'EnergyBar::EnergyBar(QProgressBar*&)'
     energyBar = new EnergyBar(progressBar);
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
progressBar = new QProgressBar(ui->statusBar);
```

means you are using pointer of QProgressBar

```
EnergyBar::EnergyBar(QProgressBar progressBar)
```

means you are NOT expecting a pointer.
use

```
EnergyBar::EnergyBar(QProgressBar * progressBar)
```

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you so much!! I did it in the creation of energyBar while trying to solve the problem but didn't think to do it in the cpp itself.